# Saving the generated excel file to the server using PHP

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to save the excel sheet generated to the server. Its saving but but the excel sheet is empty. I am using the following code.

```
$sql = "select name, email from agencies";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);    

if($resultRows>0){
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

//while($rowheading = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) { echo $rowheading->name . $sep; }
while($finfo = $result->fetch_field())
{
  printf($finfo->name . $sep);
}

print("\n");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_fields($result);$j++){
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t"; 
    print(trim(str_replace(',', " ", $schema_insert)));
    print "\n";
}


    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/myfiles/public/core/enquiry_mail_sms/file/Report.xls', $schema_insert);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

I am not understanding what is going wrong. Can someone pls guide me on this?

Comment: Diagnose. What does `$schema_insert` contain? What does `file_put_contents()` return?

Comment: When i am trying to download the excel using header its fine. header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");   
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report.xls");. But when i am trying to save it its just writing the first record and its terminating.

Comment: does a user executed php script have rights to write the file into this directory? try to change chmod

Comment: Yes i have given write permission. Its writing to the excel file, but only the last row.

Comment: so look at my answer it'll solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://php.net/file_put_contents) (emphasis mine):

> If `filename` does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, **the existing file is overwritten, unless the `FILE_APPEND` flag is set**.

(Assuming you actually mean that you only get the *last* record, not the *first*.)

Comment: So i just need to add FILE_APPEND, like this?     file_put_contents('/var/www/html/myfiles/public/core/enquiry_mail_sms/file/Report.xls', $schema_insert, FILE_APPEND);

Comment: ... except the first time you write to the file.

Comment: no still only last row is being inserted. i am still trying to rectify it or else need to use phpexcel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're overriding the file on each iteration of the loop so in the file now you'll see only the last record.

To avoid it move `file_put_contents()` outside the loop

```
$sql = "select name, email from agencies";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);    

if($resultRows>0){
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

//while($rowheading = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) { echo $rowheading->name . $sep; }
while($finfo = $result->fetch_field())
{
  printf($finfo->name . $sep);
}

print("\n");
$excelContent = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_fields($result);$j++){
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    $excelContent .= $schema_insert

    print(trim(str_replace(',', " ", $schema_insert)));
    print "\n";
}


    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/myfiles/public/core/enquiry_mail_sms/file/Report.xls', $excelContent);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: I tried putting the script outside the loop also, But same result.

Comment: You override @schemaInsert with `=` instead of `.=` better use the solution in my answer and use new variable $excelContent like I did. and use `.=` instead of `=` for concatenating new content

Comment: Now the file is writing but the only problem is all the data is coming as one row, that is there is no break after each row, its continuing in one line..

Comment: Is this line the problem?  In the code it is print(trim(str_replace(',', " ", $schema_insert)));...it should be     print(trim(str_replace(',', " ", $excelContent)));

Comment: No i just checked, thats not the issue.

Comment: what's printed won't be saved. If you want to save it then add it to $excelContent, or use output buffering